# Out-File produces alternate blank lines when viewed in Notepad

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ChildItem | Out-File temp.txt
```

I am trying to do a directory listing with PowerShell, but the temp.txt created, when viewed in Notepad, has alternate blank lines. When opened in Notepad++ it's fine.

Changing the encoding has no effect.

Comment: Can you tell us how the line endings are formatted? Make sure notepad++ [shows them](http://superuser.com/questions/382742/windows-notepad-and-notepad-show-newlines-in-same-file-differently)

Comment: Is Word Wrap active in notepad?

Comment: Thanks, Word Wrap is indeed active as the line is pretty long